# AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'my_func' on <module '__main__' from 'main.py'>

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, attributeerror, fast-ai

I want to create Python scripts, based on a notebook, to get a runtime using the same `.pkl` file.

---

On this line:

```
learn = load_learner('model.pkl', cpu=True)
```

I get this error:

```
(project) me@ubuntu-pcs:~/PycharmProjects/project$ python main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from src.train.train_model import train
  File "/home/me/PycharmProjects/project/src/train/train_model.py", line 17, in <module>
    learn = load_learner('yasmine-sftp/export_2.pkl', cpu=True)  # to run on GPU
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastai/learner.py", line 384, in load_learner
    res = torch.load(fname, map_location='cpu' if cpu else None, pickle_module=pickle_module)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 607, in load
    return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 882, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 875, in find_class
    return super().find_class(mod_name, name)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Tf' on <module '__main__' from 'main.py'>
```

This is because in order to open the `.pkl` file, I need the original function that was used to train it.

Thankfully, looking back at the notebook, `Tf(o)` is there:

```
def Tf(o):
    return '/mnt/scratch2/DLinTHDP/PathLAKE/Version_4_fastai/Dataset/CD8/Train/masks/'+f'{o.stem}_P{o.suffix}'
```

However, anywhere I place `Tf(o)` in my Python scripts I still get the same error.

**Where should I put `Tf(o)`?**

In error message: `<module '__main__' from 'main.py'>` seems to suggest to put it in `main()` or under `if __name__ ...`.

I've tried everywhere. Importing `Tf(o)` also doesn't work.

---

## Python Scripts

`main.py`:

```
import glob
from pathlib import Path

from train_model import train

ROOT = Path("folder/path")  # Detection Folder


def main(root: Path):
    train(root)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(ROOT)
```

`train_model.py`:

```
from pathlib import Path

from fastai.vision.all import *


folder_path = Path('.')

learn = load_learner('model.pkl', cpu=True)  # AttributeError
learn.load('model_3C_34_CELW_V_1.1')  # weights


def train(root: Path):
    # ...
```

---

I cannot inspect the file:

```
(project) me@ubuntu-pcs:~/PycharmProjects/project$ python -m pickletools -a model.pkl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/project/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/project/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/project/lib/python3.6/pickletools.py", line 2830, in <module>
    args.indentlevel, annotate)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/project/lib/python3.6/pickletools.py", line 2394, in dis
    for opcode, arg, pos in genops(pickle):
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/project/lib/python3.6/pickletools.py", line 2242, in _genops
    arg = opcode.arg.reader(data)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/project/lib/python3.6/pickletools.py", line 373, in read_stringnl_noescape
    return read_stringnl(f, stripquotes=False)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/project/lib/python3.6/pickletools.py", line 359, in read_stringnl
    data = codecs.escape_decode(data)[0].decode("ascii")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 63: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Problem

Why I get that error is bc the `Tf()` function was used to train the `model.pkl` file, in the same **namespace** (because it was done in a notebook file).

This [article](https://python.tutorialink.com/attributeerror-when-reading-a-pickle-file/) states:

> `pickle` is lazy and does not serialize class definitions or function
> definitions. Instead it saves a reference of how to find the class
> (the module it lives in and its name)

##### Solution

There's an extension to pickle called dill, that does serialise Python objects and functions etc. (not references) [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/dill/#:%7E:text=About%20Dill,to%20a%20python%20object%20hierarchy.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this for a similar problem by modifying load_learner from fastai.basic_train.py (fastai==1.0.61), according to ecatkins Edward Atkins
https://forums.fast.ai/t/error-loading-saved-model-with-custom-loss-function/37627/7

load_learner fails when classes used to define the model are not found in the original modules. So, override the pickle class loader (find_class) to search in the specified module.

```
import imp, sys
pickle2 = imp.load_module('pickle2', *imp.find_module('pickle'))

# The module where the class is now found.
MODULE = "MY.MODULE"

class CustomUnpickler(pickle2.Unpickler):

    def find_class(self, module, name):
        try:
            return super().find_class(module, name)
        except AttributeError:
            if module == "__main__":
                print(f"load_learner can't find {name} in original module {module}; getting it from {MODULE}")
                module = MODULE
                return super().find_class(module, name)


# Modified load_learner from fastai.basic_train.py (fastai==1.0.61), according to ecatkins Edward Atkins
# https://forums.fast.ai/t/error-loading-saved-model-with-custom-loss-function/37627/7
def load_learner2(path:PathOrStr, file:PathLikeOrBinaryStream='export.pkl', test:ItemList=None, tfm_y=None, **db_kwargs):
    "Load a `Learner` object saved with `export_state` in `path/file` with empty data, optionally add `test` and load on `cpu`. `file` can be file-like (file or buffer)"
    source = Path(path)/file if is_pathlike(file) else file
    # state = torch.load(source, map_location='cpu') if defaults.device == torch.device('cpu') else torch.load(source)
    # Use custom class loader here
    pickle2.Unpickler = CustomUnpickler
    state = torch.load(source, map_location='cpu',  pickle_module=pickle2) if defaults.device == torch.device('cpu') else torch.load(source,  pickle_module=pickle2)
    model = state.pop('model')
    src = LabelLists.load_state(path, state.pop('data'))
    if test is not None: src.add_test(test, tfm_y=tfm_y)
    data = src.databunch(**db_kwargs)
    cb_state = state.pop('cb_state')
    clas_func = state.pop('cls')
    res = clas_func(data, model, **state)
    res.callback_fns = state['callback_fns'] #to avoid duplicates
    res.callbacks = [load_callback(c,s, res) for c,s in cb_state.items()]
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to manually replicate the training environment's namespace.

In my case

```
global Tf
Tf = None
```